# I get type None instead of list

Tags: python, file, typeerror

I always get type None instead of List but it works fine in empty file when i create one

```
def change_job(name, newjob):
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as file:
        info = get_info(name) # Here I get type None
        for line in lines:
            if name in line:
                file.write(f"{info[0]} - {info[1]} - {newjob} - {info[3]}")
            else:
                file.write(line)


def get_info(name):
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = [line.split(" - ") for line in file]
        num = 0
        for i in lines:
            if name == lines[num]:
                return lines[num]
            num += 1
```

Here is empty file where everything works fine

```
import data

info = data.get_info("Johny")

print(info)
print(type(info))
```

I always get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

My target is to search by name that user writes and give new job to this person by deleting info[2] and writing new job
I want to get type List instead of None and i don't know how

I created test file where everything works fine but in main program it doesn't work for some reason

Here is what i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyProjects\Payment\main.py", line 70, in <module>
    data.change_job(wname, newjob) # wname and newjob are written by user
  File "C:\PyProjects\Payment\data.py", line 34, in change_job
    file.write(f"{info[0]} - {info[1]} - {newjob} - {info[3]}")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `get_info()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Why do you use `lines[num]` instead of `i`?

Comment: Amend that: It doesn't return anything if `name` is not found.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: The elements of `lines` are the lists returned by `line.split(" - ")`. Since `name` is a string, it will never be equal to `lines[num]`.

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that get_info() implicitly returns None, you have already truncated "data.txt" before you call the function so it could never return anything meaningful

Answer (score 1):

`lines[num]` is a list returned by `split()`. You need to compare `name` with an element of it, not the whole list. In my code below, I assume the name is the first field in the line.

There's also no need to make a list of all the lines before searching. Match the name while reading through the file.

And you should remove the newline from the end of each line.

```
def get_info(name):
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            fields = line.rstrip('\n').split(" - ")
            if fields[0] == name:
                return fields
```